# how to display uptime on emacs status bar? I am looking for /usr/bin/uptime output to be displayed on status bar

Tags: emacs, elisp, uptime

I am looking for /usr/bin/uptime output to be displayed on emacs status bar?
I am using GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on centos.

Thanks

Comment: I'd define a minor mode and use `with-idle-timer` to update the modeline (that's the status bar, right?)

Comment: Whoops, this got lost in my previous comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Basics.html .

Comment: Why isn't `M-!` `uptime` enough?

Answer (score 2):

@louxius suggestions are worth following. As to specific implementation, here's a snippet from [my `.emacs`](https://github.com/Inaimathi/emacs-utils/blob/master/dot-emacs):

```
...
;; custom modeline
(setq-default 
 mode-line-format
 (list " " 'mode-line-modified          ;; the "**" at the beginning
       "--" 'mode-line-buffer-identification    ;; buffer file name
       "--" 'mode-line-modes            ;; major and minor modes in effect
       'mode-line-position          ;; line, column, file %
       "--" '(:eval (battery-status))
       "--" '(:eval (temperature))
       "--" '(:eval (format-time-string "%I:%M" (current-time)))
       "-%-"))                  ;; dashes sufficient to fill rest of modeline.

(defun battery-status ()
  "Outputs the battery percentage from acpi."
  (replace-regexp-in-string 
   ".*?\\([0-9]+\\)%.*" " Battery: \\1%% " 
   (substring (shell-command-to-string "acpi") 0 -1)))

(defun temperature ()
  (replace-regexp-in-string
   ".*? \\([0-9\.]+\\) .*" "Temp: \\1°C "
   (substring (shell-command-to-string "acpi -t") 0 -1)))
...
```

I want different things displayed there, obviously, but this should be a decent starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks much. your .emacs helped me understanding how call external commands.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have `uptime` on my system, so I can't test this for you.  But it should give you an idea.  Seems to work on my system with `ps` substituted for `uptime`.

Perhaps someone else will offer a simpler or cleaner solution.  You might also look at `call-process` or `start-process` instead of `shell-command-to-string` --- `start-process` is async.  You might also want to consider using an idle timer --- the code here can slow Emacs down considerably, since it calls `uptime` each time the mode line is updated.

```
(setq-default 
 mode-line-format
 (list " " 'mode-line-modified
       "--" 'mode-line-buffer-identification
       "--" 'mode-line-modes
       'mode-line-position
       "--" '(:eval (shell-command-to-string "uptime"))
       "-%-"))
```

Here is another approach, which doesn't seem to slow things down noticeably:

```
(defun bar ()
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "foo")
    (erase-buffer)
    (start-process "ps-proc" "foo" "uptime")))

(setq foo (run-with-idle-timer 30 'REPEAT 'bar))

(setq-default 
 mode-line-format
 (list " " 'mode-line-modified
       "--" 'mode-line-buffer-identification
       "--" 'mode-line-modes
       'mode-line-position
       "--" '(:eval (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "foo")
                      (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max))))
       "-%-"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Lookup function `emacs-uptime`. And look this [link](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/08/customizing-mode-line.html) to customize the mode line.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply.. emacs-uptime will not give system uptime. I am looking for system uptime.